# Swift using the randomElement() function with a range

Tags: arrays, swift, random

Can you use the built in function randomElement() with the range so i can get a random element in the array with a specific range?

I am trying to get a random element in an array with a range to it, i am unable to use .random as it is an array.

I see that there is randomElemt(using:) but not sure how RandomNumberGenerator works

Comment: What about `someArray[someRange].randomElement()`?

Answer (score 1):

yes, we can use builtin function randomElement with a range on it.

```
let array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14]

// random element from range 1 to 5 
// syntax be like arrayName[startRange ... endRange].randomElement()

let randomElement = array[1...5].randomElement()
print(randomElement)
```

Comment: Are you able to structure this so that there are no repeats. So you cant have the same number in the array once the number is presented?